# Android: Connection refused error

Tags: java, server, xampp, connection, localhost

I get the error "Connection refused" when connecting to my server.
Opening the url in the browser works fine. My app has the internet permission.
Here's the stacktrace:

```
08-03 16:17:05.549 28233-28267/appname.myname.com.appname W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/appname.myname.com.appname/lib
08-03 16:17:07.336 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at appname.myname.com.appname.Search$Async$override.doInBackground(Search.java:63)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at appname.myname.com.appname.Search$Async$override.access$dispatch(Search.java)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at appname.myname.com.appname.Search$Async.doInBackground(Search.java:0)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at appname.myname.com.appname.Search$Async.doInBackground(Search.java:50)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
08-03 16:17:07.338 28233-28321/appname.myname.com.appname W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Here's my class:

```
public static class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:80/mysql/php.php");
        }catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            Log.d("dd", "e" + line);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }


}
```

[image: XAMPP CONTROL PANEL]

Is the app a problem, or my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was that I used a firewall on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

I think I had that exact problem. However, I am going through a HttpClient, which seems to be different from your code. I did this to solve my issue, it might give you a hint on what to do:

```
public static void maybeCreateHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,
                REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, USER_AGENT);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");

        // And the line that I addded to help me out:
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated and I can't use it. Isn't there another way to do this?